# adding info in django many-to-many table

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I created many-to-many connection in models.py between two tables and the third one appeared. I've stuck into the problem that i dont know how to add some info to this table.

I've been trying to import this table in shell mode but i dont know how to do it. For instance, to change table based on class 'User' i wrote:

```
from club.models import User
new = User(name='Maksym')
new.save()
```

So i'm interested in how to add some info in the table 'club_event1_users', i have attached screenshots[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 1):

> I created many-to-many connection in models.py between two tables and the third one appeared.

This is expected behavior. Django creates a many-to-many field by defining a [*junction table* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), with two `ForeignKey`s to the two models.

> I've stuck into the problem that I dont know how to add some info to this table.

Django has a [section titled *Many-to-many relationships*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) that explains how you can retrieve, and update the many-to-many table. Indeed, you can for example create a `User`, an `Event1`, and add that `Event1` to the `User`:

```
my_user = User.objects.create(name='User name')
my_event = Event.objects.create(
    name='My fancy event',
    event_date='2022-09-11',
    description='my fancy event description',
)

my_event.users.add(my_user)  # add user to the event
```

You can also access the model with:

```
Event1User = Event1.users.through  # model for the many-to-many model
```